# how do I parse a data structure composed of n lines when n is known in advanced using flex/bison?

Tags: bison, lex

Is flex/bison suitable for parsing a data structure containing N vertices composed of three floats representing x,y,z coordinates when N is known in advance?  If so, what would the parser/lexer setup look like?

## Desired structure to fill (will create an array of these)

```
struct Vertex
{
   float x;
   float y;
   float z;
};
```

Input Text

```
Vertices: n
  x1 y1 z1
  x2 y2 z2
  ...
  xN yN zN
```

## What I assume to be true (new at flex/bison so probably wrong)

### Tokens defined in parser definition

```
%token VERTICES_IDENTIFIER
%token COLON
%token NUM
```

### Lexer rules

```
Vertices { return VERTICES_IDENTIFIER;}
:        { return COLON; }
[0-9]+   |
[0-9]+"."[0-9]* {return NUM;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parser rules would go something like this, adapting from @xtof pernaud.  The list of definitions is defined recursively.

```
%{
int num_vertices;
int idx;
%}
...

program : count_definition vertex_definitions { /* check that the number of vertices 
                                                   stored = num_vertices */ 
                                              }
        ;

count_definition : VERTICES_IDENTIFIER COLON NUM { num_vertices = $3; idx = 0; 
                                                   /* allocate data structure */ 
                                                 }
                 ;

vertex_definitions : vertex_definitions vertex_definition
                   | vertex_definition
                   ;

vertex_definition : NUM NUM NUM { /* check that idx does not exceed num_vertices */
                                  store_vertex(idx++, $1, $2, $3); 
                                }
```

When I first read the question, I thought that the number of dimensions (3) was variable, as well as the number (N) of points (vertices).  If you find that you need to extend your tool to a variable number of dimensions, you may find it useful to introduce a separator (like a semicolon) between each list of floats for the vertices you are defining.

Depending on your needs, you might find that you can use a data structure that grows dynamically with each `store_vertex()` call, and then you don't need to declare `num_vertices` in your input file at all.

Answer (score 2):

You did not put your grammar file; so, I guess something like:

```
%{
int num_vertices, idx;
%}
...
%%
file: VERTICES_IDENTIFIER ':' NUM { num_vertices = $3; idx = 0; }
    | NUM NUM NUM             { set_vertice(idx++, $1, $2, $3); }
    ;
```

..and write the function `set_vertice(no, x, y, z);`

Comment: If I understand the OP correctly, this approach won't work, because the number of vertices is determined at run time, not compile time.  So, on the next run, for example, N=4 and we would need a rule that looks like 'file: NUM NUM NUM NUM`.

Comment: I reread the OP, and the number of dimensions (3) does not vary, so this approach is not flawed in that way.  Mea culpa.